# Has 2FA authenticator latency increased since upgrade to Android 9?

Tags: 9.0-pie

Since upgrading to Android 9/Pie, coworkers and I have noticed increased latency in receiving pushes to our authenticator apps (Okta, Salesforce Authenticator are my only two examples; haven't been using Google Authenticator). What used to be a wait of 1-5 seconds is typically a 10-20 second wait. Is this a known issue?  Before going to the app vendors, is there anything to explore in Android settings?

Comment: Google has again changed the scheduling of background activities for saving battery. This may have an affect on the Google push messages. If you are waiting for a push message make sure the device is active (display on and unlocked).

Comment: Based on my observation I would assume that Google has changed something in the push messaging backend because on all Android platforms the push messages now take much longer than before (several minutes instead of seconds).